# HTTP POST method returning status code 404

Tags: java, android, http-post

When I execute an API through following method, I always get 404 as response code.

```
private void execute() throws IllegalStateException, IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    Map<String, String> comment = new HashMap<String, String>();
    comment.put("accounts-groups", "customers/enterprise");
    comment.put("companyType", "customer");
    comment.put("companyName", "Test");
    String json = new GsonBuilder().create().toJson(comment, Map.class);
    Log.i(TAG, "json : "+json);

    HttpResponse response = makeRequest(URL, json);

    /*Checking response */
    if(response != null) {
        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
        int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        Log.i(TAG, "statusCode : "+statusCode);
        String result;
        // convert inputstream to string
        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

        Log.i(TAG, "result : "+result);
    }
}

private HttpResponse makeRequest(String uri, String json) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    Log.i(TAG, "uri : "+uri);
    try {
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(uri);
        httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json, HTTP.UTF_8));

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

        String signatureKey = PRIVATE_KEY + timestamp;

        byte[] bytesOfMessage = signatureKey.getBytes(HTTP.UTF_8);

        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        byte[] thedigest = md.digest(bytesOfMessage);
        char[] signature = Hex.encodeHex(thedigest);

        String finalSignature = String.valueOf(signature);

        Log.i(TAG, "finalSignature : "+finalSignature);

        httpPost.setHeader("Timestamp", ""+timestamp);
        httpPost.setHeader("Api_token", API_TOKEN);
        httpPost.setHeader("Signature" , finalSignature);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");          

        return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(httpPost);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I am not getting where am I going wrong. Can anybody please help me out?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

from wiki:

> The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code
>   indicating that the client was able to communicate with the server,
>   but the server could not find what was requested.

so, your code is OK, but server cannot find resource you are looking for. Double check if your url is correct.

---

how to pass request through fiddler proxy for debugging purposes:

```
  HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();

  // ....

  HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("192.168.1.12", 8888); // IP to your PC with fiddler proxy
  params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);

  // use params as a second parameter to: following constructor:
  // public DefaultHttpClient (ClientConnectionManager conman, HttpParams params)
```

Comment: url is correct. Same url they r using in apex code and its working fine. Don't know what's wrong in java code.

Comment: I would debug this request using fiddler on windows, that would show exactly what is going to server, and what is returning - also this allows to save such request and test it on desktop.

Comment: 1st parameter to HTTPHost is my system IP address and can please tell me what is "params" n how to get it? am on ubuntu

Comment: updated answer on how to set params, unfortunately I am not aware of any Fiddler2 alternatives on linux

Comment: There was some problem in server so for everything it was responding 404.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting 404 for POST requests because mod_headers module of Apache 2 server was not enabled. If that happens you can enable it with:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

and then restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```